# How to web scraping specific tags <p> in <div> using Python from HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

The data that I want to extract is from this website **https://www.adobe.com/support/security/advisories/apsa11-04.html**.
I just want to extract

> Release date: December 6, 2011
> Last updated: January 10, 2012
> Vulnerability identifier: APSA11-04
> CVE number: CVE-2011-2462

the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
div = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "L0C1-body"})
for p in div.findAll("p"):
    if p.find('strong'):
        print(p.text)
```

the output:

```
Release date: December 6, 2011
Last updated: January  10, 2012
Vulnerability identifier: APSA11-04
CVE number: CVE-2011-2462
Platform: All
*Note: Adobe Reader for Android and Adobe Flash Player are not affected by this issue.
```

I do not want this information. How should I filter it?

> Platform: All
> *Note: Adobe Reader for Android and Adobe Flash Player are not affected by this issue.

Comment: for efficiency you could filter during the selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than retrieve an entire collection I would go with a more efficient filtering to the first 4 sibling p tags within the selector itself with [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pprint import pprint
    
r = requests.get('https://www.adobe.com/support/security/advisories/apsa11-04.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
pprint([i.text for i in soup.select('h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(-n+4)')])
```

You could also use [limit argument](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-limit-argument):

```
pprint([i.text for i in soup.select('h2 ~ p', limit = 4)])
```

Comment: how about if the p tag is inside the div tag that has class or id ?

Comment: Can you open a question which the relevant html and current code? I think perhaps you want to add `pprint([i.text for i in soup.select('h2 ~ #someid p', limit = 4)])` or `pprint([i.text for i in soup.select('h2 ~ .someclass p', limit = 4)])` if both you can use css or syntax to combine those

Comment: Sure, I open a new question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you want always first 4 `<p>` tags after `<h2>` tag, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.adobe.com/support/security/advisories/apsa11-04.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

txt = "\n".join(
    map(lambda x: x.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "), soup.select("h2 ~ p")[:4])
)
print(txt)
```

Prints:

```
Release date: December 6, 2011
Last updated: January  10, 2012
Vulnerability identifier: APSA11-04
CVE number: CVE-2011-2462
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. It helps me a lot @Andrej Kesely .